# Safari App Extension not installed

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension

FYI I'm totally new to XCode development. I have a Safari App Extension project.

If I run it from within XCode, it adds my extension to Safari just fine. If I create an Archive, Export, and choose "Export a Development Signed Application" I can take the generated file, install it on another computer, run Safari, and see the extension. If I create an Archive, Xport, and choose "Save for Mac App Store Deployment" and then install the generated file, I see my App Extension in my Applications, but nothing shows up in Safari.

Our submission to the App Store also got denied because the extension was missing. How do I make the App Store installer install the extension so that Safari can see it?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone else who hits a similar issue, I made some progress. I did find that when I ran my installer my extension was actually being installed to Safari. I just didn't see it in my Safari extension list until I chose the 'Allow Unsigned Extensions' option under the Develop menu in Safari.

I thought that since I had my Signing area set up in the project and my machine is on the list of allowed machines in iTunes Connect that I'd be able to see it in the extensions list even without that option specified. So I uploaded the build again and they didn't reject it for that reason anymore.

As to what happened the first time, I'm not sure. Either they made a mistake, or my maybe I didn't have the correct target selected when I created the archive. I needed to make sure to have the Mac app be the target, not the extension.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was voted down. In my experience this is a valid reason for encountering the issue stated and a valid workaround. I’ll be voting it up after leaving this comment.

Comment: Hi, I tried that way, didnt work. Can you please explain more? I got rejection 2 times..

Comment: It's been a while so I don't remember exactly. Looking at this https://www.screencast.com/t/uaHVOsq5GcmQ you need  to make sure your Safari extension is selected where the red arrow is pointing, not the native app extension. I'd try  switching that  up to  see if it helps before choosing Product  -> Archive.