# Safari App Extension: Cannot find executable file that matches the value of CFBundleExecutable in nested bundle

Tags: xcode9, safari-extension, mac-app-store, safari-app-extension, macos-app-extension

I'm trying to validate my OS X application's archive, but I keep running into the following errors.

```
Bad CFBundleExecutable. Cannot find executable file that matches the value of CFBundleExecutable in the nested bundle MySafariExtension [My-Company.MyMacApp.pkg/Payload/MyMacApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/MySafariExtension.appex] property list file.
An unknown error occurred.

Bad CFBundleExecutable. Cannot find executable file that matches the value of CFBundleExecutable in the nested bundle MySafariExtension [My-Company.MyMacApp.pkg/Payload/MyMacApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/MySafariExtension.appex/Contents] property list file.
An unknown error occurred.
```

When I explore the contents of my app I can see the the nested executable in `MyMacApp.app/Contents/Plugins/MySafariExtension.appex/Contents/MacOS/MySafariExtension`
But when I install the app from a .pkg file the extension does not show in Safari. I still see the executable in the same path. I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035119/safari-app-extension-not-installed) without any luck figuring out what's going on.

Resources are scarce for Safari App Extension so hopefully some clarification as to what's going on here will help a lot of people! Thanks in advance.

UPDATE
After installing the package, if I click `Allow Unsigned Extensions` in Safari I can see the extension in safari preferences. So maybe there is an issue when signing the Safari App Extension. I'm using the same team/cert that is signing the OS X app though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with the SafariAppExtension Info.plist. I mistakenly had it targeted as a member of the SafariExtension bundle and that was causing the issue.